# Enabling Caching in Cassandra Column family through hector-API?

Tags: cassandra, hector

I am using hector-core1.0-5 from prettyprint for connecting to cassandra. Using this API I am able to create the keyspace. But I am unable to find the method which configures the "caching" property of column family. So as default it assigns "KEYS_ONLY" as "caching" value for all column families created. I wan to change this property value to "ALL" so that I can use both the key cache and row cache in cassandra.My cassandra version1.2.0. Anyone help me in finding the way to alter the "caching" property at the time a keyspace is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not support for get or set caching in ColumnFamilyDefinition interface. Hector community has to patch the code.

Answer (score 0):

No idea about Hector as such. But we are using Playorm for Cassandra and it uses Caches like hibernate. Read more information at http://buffalosw.com/wiki/Caching-in-Playorm/.